Using Nuxt 3 and Pinia: How to Persist Session ID Across API Requests Using Universal Cookies?
I am building a Nuxt 3 application using Pinia for state management. I have an issue with persisting the session ID across API requests using the universal-cookie library.
Problem Description
Every time I make an API request to add a product to the cart, a new session ID is generated instead of using the existing session ID. As a result, the subsequent request to fetch cart data also fails to use the same session ID, leading to a new session being created. This causes the cart to appear empty, as each request uses a different session.
Current Setup

API Request to Add Product to Cart:

I send a POST request to add a product to the cart.
The response includes a session_id in the response data.


API Request to Get Cart Data:

I send a GET request to fetch the cart data.
The session ID should be included in the request headers as a Cookie, but it doesn't seem to persist.



Expected Behavior

The session_id returned from the first API request should be stored and reused for subsequent API requests.
The session ID should be included in the request headers as laravel_session for all requests after it is initially received.

Code Implementation
services/cart.ts
import { ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART_URL, CART_DATA_URL, EMTPY_CART_URL, REMOVE_CART_PRODUCT_URL } from '@/constants/urls';
import { type ApiResponse } from '@/types/api';
import { type CartItem } from '@/types/cart';
import { useCookieStore } from '@/stores/CookieStore';

export const addProductToCart = async (productDetailId: number, quantity: number): Promise<ApiResponse<{ session_id: string }>> => {
  const cookieStore = useCookieStore();
  const sessionId = cookieStore.getSessionCookie;
  console.log('sessionId', sessionId);

  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.set('cookie', sessionId || '');

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('product_detail_id', productDetailId.toString());
  formData.append('quantity', quantity.toString());

  const response = await $fetch<ApiResponse<{ session_id: string }>>(ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers
  });
  
  if (!sessionId) {
    cookieStore.updateSessionId(response.data.session_id);
  }

  return response;
};

export const getCartData = async (): Promise<ApiResponse<CartItem[]>> => {
  const cookieStore = useCookieStore();

  const response = await fetch(CART_DATA_URL, {
    headers: {
      'Cookie': cookieStore.getSessionCookie,
    },
  });

  const data = await response.json() as ApiResponse<CartItem[]>;
  return data;
};

stores/CookieStore.ts
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

const cookies = new Cookies();

export const useCookieStore = defineStore('CookieStore', {
  state: () => ({
    sessionId: cookies.get('laravel_session') || null,
  }),
  actions: {
    setSessionId(sessionId: string) {
      this.sessionId = sessionId;
      cookies.set('laravel_session', sessionId, { path: '/', maxAge: 3 * 24 * 60 * 60, expires: new Date(Date.now() + 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) });
    },
    getSessionId() {
      return this.sessionId;
    },
    updateSessionId(sessionId: string) {
      this.setSessionId(sessionId);
      this.isValidSession(sessionId);
    },
    isValidSession(sessionId: string | null) {
      if (sessionId) {
        const expires = new Date(sessionId.split('.')[1]);
        if (expires > new Date()) {
          return true;
        } else {
          cookies.remove('laravel_session');
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
    loadSessionFromCookies() {
      this.sessionId = cookies.get('laravel_session');
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getSessionCookie: (state) => {
      return state.sessionId ? `laravel_session=${state.sessionId}` : '';
    },
  },
});

plugins/cookies.ts
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import { useCookieStore } from '@/stores/CookieStore';

interface Req {
  headers: {
    cookie: string;
  };
}

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const cookieStore = useCookieStore();
  cookieStore.loadSessionFromCookies();

  const req: Req | null = nuxtApp.ssrContext?.req as Req | null;
  const cookies = req && req.headers ? new Cookies(req.headers.cookie || '') : new Cookies();

  nuxtApp.provide('cookies', cookies);

  // Define global property only if it doesn't already exist
  if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(nuxtApp.vueApp.config.globalProperties, '$cookies')) {
    Object.defineProperty(nuxtApp.vueApp.config.globalProperties, '$cookies', {
      get() {
        return cookies;
      }
    });
  }
});

What I Have Tried

Ensured that the session ID is correctly stored and retrieved using the universal-cookie library.
Verified that the session_id is correctly updated in the CookieStore after the initial request.
Checked that the session ID is being passed in the request headers.

Issue
Despite these implementations, each request still generates a new session ID, and the session is not maintained across different API requests. This leads to issues like cart items not being persisted.
How can I ensure that the session ID is consistently reused across all API requests in my Nuxt 3 application?
EDIT: I'm adding cors middleware for reference
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class Cors
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $allowedOrigins = [
            'http://localhost:3000',
            'https://example.com',
        ];

        $origin = $request->headers->get('Origin');
        //Log::info('Origin: ' . $origin);

        if (in_array($origin, $allowedOrigins)) {
            $headers = [
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => $origin, // Allow the specific origin
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true', // Allow credentials
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Cookie, Origin, Authorization',
            ];

            if ($request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
                // Return the preflight response
                return response()->json('Ok', 200, $headers);
            }

            foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
                $response->headers->set($key, $value);
            }
        }

        return $response;
    }
}

